# Does VueJS prerender, or re-render?

Tags: angular, vue.js, angular-universal

Angular Universal breaks down two models for [Server Rendering Flows](https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/)

- Flow for server **pre-rendering**

  1. Generate static HTML with build tool
  2. Deploy generated HTML to a CDN
  3. Server view served up by CDN
  4. Server view to client view transition (see below)
- Flow for server **re-rendering**

  1. HTTP GET request sent to the server
  2. Server generates a page that contains rendered HTML and inline 
     JavaScript for Preboot (and you can optionally add serialized data for caching purposes)
  3. Server view to client view transition (see below)

Which of those models best explains VueJS?

Answer (score 0):

By default it is essentially described by your re-rendering bullet points.  You can also do pre-rendering if desired though (see SSR vs Prerendering here https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/).